# Invalid Json in AWS Custom Authorize .Net Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I have built a custom authorizer for AWS in .net core. When testing it from API Gateway Console I am receiving ResponseCode 500 with this error.

```
Execution log for request 0566bf99-cfb5-11e8-b203-65db1a667292
Sun Oct 14 13:28:22 UTC 2018 : Starting authorizer: i07xnl for request: 0566bf99-cfb5-11e8-b203-65db1a667292
Sun Oct 14 13:28:22 UTC 2018 : Incoming identity: **ds
Sun Oct 14 13:28:22 UTC 2018 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:278483347755:function:GetPolicy/invocations
Sun Oct 14 13:28:22 UTC 2018 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=0566bf99-cfb5-11e8-b203-65db1a667292, Authorization=************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************4e3e8c, X-Amz-Date=20181014T132822Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=k8ate5przg, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:278483347755:k8ate5przg/authorizers/i07xnl, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_k8ate5przg, X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEA0aDBDj/T/Y58E+lkgRcyK3A5EXzDygzB0DzIFN36D/LMM0uCMn70NDKnpualhTEKEe8Zj/a6/nSFVwDSmQty8r2b/ezWcJoQCQztPHDiTFFu7I/4vvoGuH6P3REduQn8knZGVkBAOFTi/EIcnLNBoWjWQXrO8BszGKdoykJ3BrTIq+2dbyfOUdIcmCwGGyC/UzGn5B+fkNcSJT94yfemVcfEiuncnx6snRekDYzRZWXW1+ZzxPoMINpykNTYbKCnG5pNzPF7j2xxH7zyfYtmsVaMaq5zBGqT3eGzUonM4k/7FIRwOB6SxRUIHrO/fboa3QW+z7+iQEtqWg7DDO [TRUNCATED]
Sun Oct 14 13:28:22 UTC 2018 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"type":"TOKEN","methodArn":"arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:278483347755:k8ate5przg/ESTestInvoke-stage/GET/","authorizationToken":"sdds"}
Sun Oct 14 13:28:22 UTC 2018 : Sending request to https://lambda.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:278483347755:function:GetPolicy/invocations
Sun Oct 14 13:28:24 UTC 2018 : Authorizer result body before parsing: {"Version":"10/14/18","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Action":["apigateway: POST"],"Resource":["arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:278483347755:function:GetPolicy"]}]}
Sun Oct 14 13:28:24 UTC 2018 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid JSON in response: {"Version":"10/14/18","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Action":["apigateway: POST"],"Resource":["arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:278483347755:function:GetPolicy"]}]}
Sun Oct 14 13:28:24 UTC 2018 : AuthorizerConfigurationException
```

The Invalid Json is this:

```
{
    "Version": "10/14/18",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": ["apigateway: POST"],
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:278483347755:function:GetPolicy"]
    }]
}
```

To me this seems Okay. Here, Action value is taken from AWS documentation and Resource is the ARN for my custom authorizer lambda method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response isn't correct for a custom authorisation lambda.

You can see the full details here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html), however for your example you need to return:

```
{
  "principalId": "user",
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:278483347755:k8ate5przg/ESTestInvoke-stage/GET/"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Specifically you need to nest your policy in a `policyDocument` key, and the permission you're granting is *not* to be able to `POST` to API Gateway, but to be allowed to invoke the function behind the gateway.

Comment: I created the Json as mentioned by you, I did not knew the Version is fixed. How I can get details about the version and the Actions for lambda method inside .net SDK?

Comment: Version actually refers to the version of the structure of that policy document object (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_version.html). Everything in that document is an IAM Policy, and so is agnostic from any language specific SDK. https://iam.cloudonaut.io/ provides a really good resource for seeing all the IAM actions and resources, while https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies.html gives details on how to build a policy document.